# Unable to prevent spacebar default action in firefox

Tags: jquery

There is a window which opens on clicking a button. This window has few buttons. On tabbing to the close button and hitting either space or enter will close the window. I want to restrict closing the window on hitting space bar.
It works completely fine in IE and Chrome but not in Firefox.
I tried using event.which == 32 and event.keyCode == 32 but with no luck.

```
function disablespacekey()
{
  $(document).on("keydown", function (event)
  {        
    if (event.keyCode == 32)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
}
```

In firefox when I click the button, control comes till event.preventDefault() but this doesnt work and closed the window.

Comment: can you please post jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, preventDefault() method with keydown and keypress events is not working in firefox.
I used preventDefault() method with keyup and is working firefox.
Thank you all for your inputs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me.i used jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("keydown", function (event)
  {        
    if (event.keyCode == 32)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
});
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/zHVGZm6zqsgtAtY4I0NY?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try this, tested on firefox also:

```
function disablespacekey()
    {
      $(document).on("keydown", function (event)
      {        
        return event.which !== 32;
    });
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DdV3k/5/)

Comment: Control comes till return statement but is closing the window in Firefox. In chrome and IE space bar hit is restricted and the window doesn't close.